# How to retrieve Post method error response in react from node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am new to react. I want to retrieve the Post method error response from node js in my React code

Backend

```js
const user = new userModel(_.pick(req.body, ["name", "email", "password"]));
  const { error } = new userValidation(
    _.pick(req.body, ["name", "email", "password"])
  );
  if (error) return res.status(403).send(error.details[0].message);
  const email = await userModel.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (email) return res.status(400).send("Email already exists");
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  user.password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

  try {
    const result = await userModel.create(user);
    res.status(200).json(_.pick(result, ["_id", "name", "email"]));
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404).send(err);
  }
};
```

Frontend

```js
import { React, useRef, useState } from "react";

const [user, setUser] = useState({
  name: "",
  email: "",
  Password: "",
});
const { name, email, password } = user;
const myForm = new FormData();

myForm.set("name", name);
myForm.set("email", email);
myForm.set("password", password);
// myForm.set("avatar", avatar);

const registerSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    registerUser(myForm).then((res) => {
      toast.success(`${res.data.name}, You are registered Successfully`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

I want to show the response "Email already exists" which I sent from this code

Comment: This looks like code from the backend, can you also add the frontend (react) code to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do in the try catch like:

```
 catch (error) {
        
        error("Email already exists");
    }
```

Then in the context if you have a context or in the view you have to do this:

```
const [error, setError] = useState("");

<AuthContext.Provider
            value={{                
                error,          
            }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
```

```
{error && ( <ErrorContainer size="large">
            <Text variant="error">{error}</Text>
            </ErrorContainer>
    )}
```

ErrorContainer looks for exmaple like:

```
export const ErrorContainer = styled.View`
    max-width: 300px;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: center;
    margin-top: ${(props) => props.theme.space[2]};
    margin-bottom: ${(props) => props.theme.space[2]};
`;
```